# Реализация факториала через класс

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class FactorialClass {
public:
    int factorial(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return i * factorial(i-1);
        }
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << factorial(n);
    }

};

int main() {

    FactorialClass obj;
    obj.factorial();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Не понимаю, почему не работает - выдает ошибку

> ```
> функция принимает 0 аргументов
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция

```
int factorial(int i)
```

принимает параметр типа `int` и `int` же возвращает.

Где в

```
obj.factorial();
```

параметр?...

Это уж не говоря о том, что у вас какая-то странная функция с неработающим куском

```
 int n;
 std::cin >> n;
 std::cout << factorial(n);
```

Думаю, вы хотели что-то вроде

```
#include <iostream>

class FactorialClass {
public:

    void factorial()
    {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << factorial(n) << std::endl;
    }

    int factorial(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return i * factorial(i-1);
        }
    }

};

int main() {

    FactorialClass obj;
    obj.factorial();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: о точно спасибо за инфу, а то я через функцию разобрался как факториал вычислить с классами затупил))

Comment: Ну, если вас ответ устроил - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый.